# Could not override FOSUserBundle default register form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle, symfony-forms

I'm new to symfony, I'm using symfony 2.8.
I installed FOSUserBundle and it works just fine, the problem is that i want to add a field to the registration form I followed the steps in [FOSUserBundle documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html) But nothing has changed and I don't get an error.
I don't know what exactly am I missing.
This is my User entity:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=3,
     *     max=255,
     *     minMessage="The name is too short.",
     *     maxMessage="The name is too long.",
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
    protected $name;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

This is the RegistrationType.php :

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Form/RegistrationType.php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'fos_user_registration';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }
}
```

The app/config/services.yml file:

```
parameters:
    #parameter_name: value

services:
    app.form.registration:
        class: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: app_user_registration }
```

And this is the section related to FOSUserBundle in app/config/config.yml:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            name: app_user_registration
```

I couldn't find what I'm missing.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you show your error?

Comment: I don't get an error, it's just nothing changes. I don't get the new field in the form.

Comment: Did you run `doctrine:schema:update`?

Comment: yeah I did, It adds the new colum to the table but the  register form remains the same.

Comment: Did you try `cache:clear`?

Comment: yep, and the problem remains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to you `form`:

```
/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User'
    ));
}
```

if you are using Symfony < 2.8

```
# app/config/config.yml
fos_user:
    # ...
    registration:
        form:
            type: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationType
```

if you are using Symfony > 2.8

```
# app/config/config.yml
fos_user:
    # ...
    registration:
        form:
            name: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationType
```

Comment: Yes, That did it! Thank you so much!

Comment: I was using the "name" instead of the "type" in config.yml and i'm using symfony 2.8